# How to open a .pdf file in dashbord node-red

Tags: node-red

I would like to know, how to open a PDF file using dashboard in node-red on rpi3. The goal is to open this file in Dashboard in frame:

[image]

I try use +Link in Dashboard options but it doesn't work :

[image]

I get messege:`Cannot GET /home/pi/Desktop/Some.pdf`

If this proper way?
I use:
Node-RED version: v0.18.3
Dashboard version 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

The entry in the link box needs to be a proper URL not just a path to the file. If you really mean to link to a local file then the correct URL is:

```
file:///home/pi/Desktop/Some.pdf
```

But if you want to access this file from a browser running on a different machine to Node-RED then this will not work.

You have 2 options

1. Use the `httpStatic` option in the settings.js ([doc](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration)) to allow you to share files via http
2. Use a `http-in` and `http-response` pair with a `file` node to server that specific file

Comment: Ok I try correct URL for website and it works. It need to be complete address with http://....
But when I use use option 'iframe' and not 'New tab' doesn't work.

And when I try open pdf file after that i put 
'file:///home/pi/Desktop/Some.pdf'
its dosn't work at all. Even i try with option 'New tab' it just open new but dosn't display pdf.

Comment: I tested option "iframe" with view different website and for some it open web site and for other not. For example it works for "www.wp.pl" and for :"https://stackoverflow.com" it dosen't opened. 

One think more. Even if open website the frame from dashboard is disappears.